# How to call function as initial value of state variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, logic

I Have a function :

```
async function setAllValues(value) {
        await stableSort(rows, getComparator(order, orderBy))
            .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
            .forEach((row) => {
                temp = { ...temp, [row.id]: value };
            });
        console.log('| temp', temp);
        return temp;
    }
```

and a state variable:

```
const [rowValues, setRowValues] = useState(setAllValues(false));
```

Now I want the default value of `rowValues` to be `temp`(the variable returned from the function), but everytime i log `rowValues` it logs as a promise. Everytime i call `setRowValues`, it calls the function `setAllValues` too(i know this as temp is logged in the function). How do i achieve the desired outcome?

Comment: Async functions **always** return a `Promise` object. If you are using an async operation, such as fetching data, then you should set the state in a `useEffect` hook. But besides that, do you really need async / await here?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I removed the async await as you said, but every time i call the `setRowValues` it calls the `setAllValues` as well, i want it to call it only while initializing the default value of the state variable.

Comment: Could you add more of your component and how you actually use the `rowValues` state? I'm thinking you'll need to adjust some of the structure and the way you set the default state.

Answer (score 0):

Use an effect to set the initial value instead once when the page has loaded:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    setAllValues(false)
        .then(setRowValues)
}, [])
```

Keep the function outside the body of the component so React doesn't complain about it not being in the dependency array.

If you don't need `setAllValues` to be `async`, remove `async` `await` and set it as initial state with

```js
const [rowValues, setRowValues] = useState() => setAllValues(false))
```

Currently you're executing it on every render.

Comment: I cant keep the function body outside the component since it uses variables defined within it

Comment: Then put it in the effect

Answer (score 0):

[Now that you don't use `async/await` anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72498117/how-to-call-function-as-initial-value-of-state-variable/72498585#comment128069725_72498117), you can just pass a function to `useState`, as explained in ["Lazy initial state"](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state):

```
const [rowValues, setRowValues] = useState(() => setAllValues(false));
```

The function will only be called the first time the component renders.

Comment: https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#yjpcwng93pd6lf50zsmkss  
find what ive done on the link above.   
Ive done as you said, but im still getting the default value of `rowValues` as `[]` instead of object with default values as false

Comment: Verify that `rows`, `page` and `rowsPerPage` is what you expect it to be and that `stableSort` returns what you expect. Also your code can't work if `temp` isn't initialized anywhere.

Comment: yep they are as expected, temp is also initialized before the function